# Inserting into a Hash Table

Tags: c, hashtable

I am trying to get words inserted into a hash table. When I run the code, it's supposed to give me a list of the frequency of each word, but it just gives me nothing.

I'm sure it's either to do with my print function, or my insert function, probably more my insert function. I know it's isn't mylib.h, but I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong.

It doesn't insert anything into my table or print it. I'm not really sure what's going on.

hashtable.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "htable.h"

    struct htablerec {
       char **key;
       int *frequencies;
       int num_keys;
       int capacity;
    };

    void *emalloc(size_t s) {
       void *result = malloc(s);
       if (NULL == result) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       return result;
    }

    htable htable_new(int capacity) {
       int i;
       htable h = emalloc(sizeof * h);
       h->capacity = capacity;
       h->num_keys = 0;
       h->frequencies = emalloc(h->capacity * sizeof h->frequencies[0]);
       h->key = emalloc(h->capacity * sizeof h->key[0]);
       for (i = 0; i < h->capacity; i++) {
          h->frequencies[i] = 0;
          h->key[i] = NULL;
       }
       return h;
    }

    void htable_free(htable h) {
       free(h->frequencies);
       free(h->key);
       free(h);
    }

    static unsigned int htable_word_to_int(char *word) {
       unsigned int result = 0;
       while (*word != '\0') {
          result = (*word++ + 31 * result);
       }
       return result;
    }

    int htable_insert(htable h, char *str) {
       int i;
       /*convert string to integer*/
       unsigned int index = htable_word_to_int(str);
       /*calculate index to insert into hash table*/
       int remainder = index%h->capacity;
       /*once calculated position in the hash table, 3 possibilities occur*/
       /*no string in this positon, copy string to that position, increment number of keys, return 1*/
       if (h->key[remainder] == NULL) {
          h->frequencies[remainder] = 1;
          h->num_keys++;
          return 1;
       }
       /*the exact same string is at the position, increment frequency at that position, return frequency*/
       if (strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) == 0) {
          h->frequencies[remainder]++;
          return h->frequencies[remainder];
       }/*a string is at that position, but it isnt the rightone, keep moving along the array
       until you find either an open space or the string you are looking for*/
       if (h->key[remainder] != NULL && strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) != 0) {
       /*you may need to wrap back around to the beginning of the table, so each time you add
       to the position you should also mod by the table capacity.*/
          for (i = 0; i <= h->capacity; i++) {
             if (h->key[remainder] != NULL && h->capacity ==  i) {
                i = 0;
                }
                /*no string in this positon, copy string to that position, increment number of keys*/
                if (h->key[remainder] == NULL) {
                h->frequencies[remainder] = 1;
                h->num_keys++;
             }
             /*if you find the string you were looking for, increment the frequecny at the position
             and return the frequency*/
             if (strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) == 0) {
                h->frequencies[remainder]++;
                return h->frequencies[remainder];
             }
          }   
       }
       /*if you have kept looking for an open space but there isnt one, the hash table must be full so return 0*/
       return 0;
    }

    void htable_print(htable h, FILE *stream) {
       int i;
       for(i = 0; i < h->capacity; i++) {
          if(h->key[i] != NULL) {
             fprintf(stream, "%d%s\n", h->frequencies[i], h->key[i]);
          }
       }
    }
```

htable.h:

```
#ifndef HTABLE_H_
#define HTABLE_H_

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct htablerec *htable;

extern void htable_free(htable h);
extern int htable_insert(htable h, char *str);
extern htable htable_new(int capacity);
extern void htable_print(htable h, FILE *stream);
extern int htable_search(htable h, char *str);

#endif
```

mylib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylib.h"
#include "htable.h"

int main(void) {
   htable h = htable_new(18143);
   char word[256];

   while (getword(word, sizeof word, stdin) !=EOF) {
      htable_insert(h, word);
   }

   htable_print(h, stdout);
   htable_free(h);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

mylib.h:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getword(char *s, int limit, FILE *stream) {
   int c;
   char *w = s;
   assert(limit > 0 && s != NULL && stream != NULL);

   /*skip to the start fo the word */
   while (!isalnum(c = getc(stream)) && EOF != c)
      ;
   if(EOF == c) {
      return EOF;
   } else if (--limit > 0) { /*reduce limit by 1 to allow for the \0 */
      *w++ = tolower(c);
   }

   while(--limit > 0) {
      if(isalnum(c = getc(stream))) {
         *w++ = tolower(c);
      } else if ('\'' == c) {
         limit++;
      } else {
            break;
         }
      }
      *w = '\0';
      return w - s;
   }
```

Comment: If you are not sure what is going on, fire up your debugger and put a breakpoint in the `htable_insert` function and step through the function a line of code at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `h->key[remainder]` to anything in `htable_insert`, so `h->key[i]` is still `NULL` for all `i` when you call `htable_print`.

Comment: so when i set int remainder = index%h->capacity; i need to set h->key[remainder] to remainder? you think that would solve my problem?

Comment: Based on the rest of the code, it seems like every time you call h->num_keys++, you also need to set h->key[remainder] to the string that you're adding. (It really seems like the thing you're calling remainder is the key in the hashmap, and you have used h->key[i] as if it's storing the value in the hashmap.)

Comment: i'm sorry, you're kind of confusing me. the remainder is suppose to work out the position of which we're going to end up in the hash table, the i is a counter that goes around the hash table, and loops back to the start if we reach the end of the hask table. I'm really not quite sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: Sorry. I just haven't completely read your code. You should probably just ignore my comment about the keys and the values. The point is that when you're checking to see if a position has been used, you're using `strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) != 0`, but you never actually give `h->key[remainder]` a value. It seems like every time you're doing `h->num_keys++`, you also want a copy like veer mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> /*no string in this positon, copy string to that position, increment number of keys, return 1*/
> if (h->key[remainder] == NULL) {
>    h->frequencies[remainder] = 1;
>    h->num_keys++;
>    return 1;
> }
> ...
> /*no string in this positon, copy string to that position, increment number of keys*/
> if (h->key[remainder] == NULL) {
>     h->frequencies[remainder] = 1;
>     h->num_keys++;
> }
> ```

You never copy the string. Try something like...

```
char *key = emalloc(strlen(str) + 1);
strcpy(str, key);
h->key[remainder] = key;
```

Comment: Omg, I don't either! Thank you.